# Library not loaded: no suitable image found

Tags: ios, xcode

While  staring my app in iOS (iPad Mini 2) I getting this crashing message:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/SomeCustomFramework.framework/SomeCustomFramework   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1F5CC30F-4CBB-4AF2-A2F4-E88BB88F57BF/myapp.app/myapp
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1F5CC30F-4CBB-4AF2-A2F4-E88BB88F57BF/myapp.app/Frameworks/SomeCustomFramework.framework/SomeCustomFramework:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1F5CC30F-4CBB-4AF2-A2F4-E88BB88F57BF/myapp.app/Frameworks/SomeCustomFramework.framework/SomeCustomFramework:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1F5CC30F-4CBB-4AF2-A2F4-E88BB88F57BF/myapp.app/Frameworks/SomeCustomFramework.framework/SomeCustomFramework:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture

All preferences for both framework and base application are the same (default). What have I missed?

Comment: What architecture is the framework built for?  (Check by using the `file` command from the terminal.)

Comment: @PhillipMills , standard: armv7 , arm64

Comment: @PhillipMills , valid archs : armv7, arm7s , arm64

Comment: That looks like your build settings.  If you actually open up the .app directory of the product on disk and check "../Frameworks/SomeCustomFramework.framework/SomeCustomFramework" does it say the same thing?

Comment: oh. it was incorrectly setup project's Embedded binaries.